# Entity Framework Spatial Aggregates Functions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, spatial

Sql Server has useful spatial aggregate functions which are described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2011/04/27/spatial-aggregates-in-sql-server-denali.aspx). 
Just wondering are they available through Entity Framework API?
For instance can I use Envelope Aggregate in Entity Framework LINQ query?
 There is a class in Entity Framework 6 which calls [SqlSpatialFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlspatialfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that provided some SQL Server spatial functions but I couldn't find EnvelopeAggregate function.

 Does Entity Framework provide any equivalent API or I need to use raw TSQL query>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a LINQ-based solution, but for reference here's an example using a raw SQL query in Entity Framework 6:

```
// Need to use SQL since EF doesn't support spatial aggregates
var querySql = @"SELECT 
Geometry::UnionAggregate([SpatialBounds]) 
FROM [dbo].[LandgateLocation] 
WHERE [Distict] = (@p0)";

var polygon = await dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbGeometry>(querySql, request.District).SingleAsync();
```